# Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, springfox

We have updated spring-boot as part of the vulnerability fix
And now when application start we have

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56)
at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113)
at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89)
at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107)
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91)
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82)
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
... 19 common frames omitted

current spring boot version - 2.7.11
spring boot cloud version - 2021.0.5
spring fox - 3.0.0(was updated from 2.9.2)

Thank you in advance for your cooperation(varian with downgrade spring boot it's not good solution for me)

Tried add in application.yml this line 'spring:mvc:pathmatch:matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher' doesn't help because I have spring-boot-actuator:2.7.11